# Creating WCS using LAS Dataset

Tags: las, wcs, image-service

I am looking for a way to serve up an LAS Dataset in order for others to consume it and to analyze it. So far what I've read says that it must be a map, raster/mosiac Dataset, or GDB. Is there a way to serve up an LAS Dataset specifically? It would need to be through proprietary services (i.e. ESRI).

https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.6/publish-services/linux/wcs-services.htm

Comment: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/imagery/workflows/best-practices/sharing-lidar-points-for-visualization-on-the-web.htm